# how to access the list in different function

Tags: python, list, function

I have made a class in which there are 3 functions.

1. def maxvalue
2. def min value
3. def getAction

In the def maxvalue function, I have made a list of actions. I want that list to be accessed in def getaction function so that I can reverse the list and then take out the first entry from it. How can do i that??

```
 def getAction(self,gamestate):
      bestaction.reverse()
      return bestaction[0]




 def maxvalue(gameState, depth):

    actions = gameState.getLegalActions(0);
    v = -9999
    bestaction = []
    for action in actions:
      marks = minvalue(gameState.generateSuccessor(0, action), depth, 1)
      if(v < marks):
       v = marks
       bestaction.append(action)
    return v
```

It is giving me an error....."global name bestaction is not defined"

Comment: Just `return` that list? What's the problem??

Comment: Providing some code would definitely help us answer.

Comment: can u plz see the question again...Im getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to post actual code - it makes it easier to see what's happening.

With that said, you probably want something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def max_value(self):
        # assigning your list like this will make it accessible 
        # from other methods in the class
        self.list_in_max_value = ["A", "B", "C"]

    def get_action(self):
        # here, we're doing something with the list
        self.list_in_max_value.reverse()
        return self.list_in_max_value[0]

>>> my_class = MyClass()
>>> my_class.max_value()
>>> my_class.get_action()
"C"
```

You might want to read through [the python class tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: @Shilpa: You forgot the `self` before `bestaction`.

Comment: i tried it, but the errors is still occuring as main class minimax doesnot have bestaction...can you see my other question.

Answer (score 1):

Either define the list as a class attribute or as an instance attribute, then all the methods will be able to access it

If you'd like to post your class, it'll be easier to show you what I mean

Here is an example making it a class attribute

```
class Foo(object):
    list_of_actions = ['action1', 'action2']
    def max_value(self):
        print self.list_of_actions
    def min_value(self):
        print self.list_of_actions        
    def get_action(self):
        list_of_actions = self.list_of_actions[-2::-1]
        print list_of_actions
```

And here as an instance attribute

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_actions = ['action1', 'action2']
    def max_value(self):
        print self.list_of_actions
    def min_value(self):
        print self.list_of_actions        
    def get_action(self):
        list_of_actions = self.list_of_actions[-2::-1]
        print list_of_actions
```

**Edit** since you posted code, here is how to fix your problem

```
def getAction(self,gamestate):
    self.bestaction.reverse()
    return bestaction[0]

def maxvalue(gameState, depth):
    actions = gameState.getLegalActions(0);
    v = -9999
    self.bestaction = []
    for action in actions:
        marks = minvalue(gameState.generateSuccessor(0, action), depth, 1)
        if v < marks:
            v = marks
        self.bestaction.append(action)
    return
```

Comment: Have +1: Nice detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a side effect to create an attribute of the class..

```
class Example(object):
  def maxvalue(self, items)
    self.items = items
    return max(item for item in items)
```