# list query, functions in function

Tags: python, function, list

i have a function:

```
       I need to first reverse the list and then take an entry from it.
```

Earlier, I was making the 3 functions but now I am defining the main function and the other 2 functions in it.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Why does `return theAction` not work?

Comment: I need to use the list defined in the def maxvalue function. I need to return its 1st entry by reversing it.

Comment: Your indentation is all wrong.

Comment: identation is not a problm..I just need to know how to return the element of list. In copying code from the original place, the identation error occured.I m not getting the identation error

Comment: @Shilpa: Which element of which list? There are so many lists.

Comment: bestaction list....i want to first reverse it and then take out its first element. I need to return it for the function getAction at the end

Comment: @Shilpa: So you mean the *last* element of the `bestaction` list...

Comment: yes...for teh def getAction...I made 2 functions in it.....and now I want to return the last element of it

Comment: As with you last question, don't post similar questions multiple times. This here is clearly a successor of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385796. Post *one* question with a description that makes the actual problem comprehensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is very unpythonic. Remember Python is not C.

1. The semicolon is optional.
2. The parenthesis in an `if` is optional.
3. To get the last element of list `a`, use `a[-1]`, not reversing `a` then get its first element.
4. Use the built-in functions! Your modified `maxagent` can be written simply using the `max` function:

   ```
   def maxagent(gamestate, depth):
       actions = gamestate.getLegalActions(0)
       filteredactions = filter(lambda action: action != Directions.STOP, actions)
       # alternatives: 
       #    filteredactions = filter(Directions.STOP.__ne__, actions)
       #    filteredactions = (a for a in actions if a != Directions.STOP)
       bestaction = max(filteredactions,
                        key=lambda action: self.minvalue(
                                             gamestate.generateSuccessor(0, action),
                                             depth, 1
                                           ))
       return bestaction
   ```

If you need the score too, consider returning a *tuple*.

```
def maxagent(gamestate, depth)
    actions = gamestate.getLegalActions(0)
    scores = ( (self.minvalue(gamestate.generateSuccessor(0, a), depth, 1), a)
               for a in actions if a != Directions.STOP
             )
    return max(scores)
...
score, action = maxagent(gamestate, depth)
```